# Cannot filter on date field converted from numeric

Tags: r, date-conversion

Using R, when I query a sqlite database, it returns  a date field as a double.

When I convert this to a date field, it looks OK but I cannot filter on it. Here is a toy example

```
df <- data.frame(dbl = c(1408258800, 1409382000, 1324108800))
df$dt <- as.Date(df$dbl/(60*60*24), origin= '1970-01-01')

str(df)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ dbl: num  1.41e+09 1.41e+09 1.32e+09
# $ dt : Date, format: "2014-08-17" "2014-08-30" "2011-12-17"

df[df$dbl==1408258800,]
#         dbl         dt
#1 1408258800 2014-08-17


df[df$dt=="2014-08-17",]
#[1] dbl dt 
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

   OR

df[df$dt==as.Date("2014-08-17"),]
#[1] dbl dt 
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Guess I'm missing something pretty basic either on obtaining initial result as date field
or subsequent processing

TIA

Comment: Did you try `as.character`? e.g. `df[as.character(df$dt) == "2014-08-17", ]`

Comment: whoops. Looks like that might be obvious solution

Answer (score 1):

`as.Date` expects the number of days since the origin as input. However, you pass it decimal numbers. Consequently:

```
as.numeric(df$dt[1])
#[1] 16299.29
as.numeric(as.Date("2014-08-17"))
#[1] 16299
```

And these are not identical. I think `as.Date.numeric` should handle this differently or give a warning, but it's not exactly a bug.

Use integer division instead:

```
df$dt <- as.Date(df$dbl %/% (60*60*24), origin= '1970-01-01')

df[df$dt==as.Date("2014-08-17"),]
#         dbl         dt
#1 1408258800 2014-08-17
```

Comment: I found the same thing, but unlike you, I do think this is a bug.

Comment: @BondedDust It's at least not documented adequately. Feel free to submit a bug report.

Comment: The root problem is in `+.Date` which returns `structure(unclass(e1) + unclass(e2), class = "Date")` without checking if the second argument is an integer number.

Comment: That's one possibility. Alternatively `as.Date.numeric` could be wrapping `trunc` around the "x".

Comment: @BondedDust I don't think `Date` objects should be a decimal numbers internally. I'd expect them to be positive full numbers (i.e., mathematical integers). Thus `+.Date` shouldn't return such strange Date objects.

Comment: I basically agree. We are only mildly disagreeing about implementation.